# How to insert a dataframe to mongodb using rmongodb

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rmongodb

I have following dataframe

[image]

how can I insert it to mongoDB using rmongodb?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a list of JSON objects, each of which will be inserted into the Mongo DB:

```
library(rjson)
df <- data.frame(rowLabels=c("Birrarung Marr", "Bourke Street Mall (North)", "Bourke Street Mall (South)", "Flagstaff Station", "Flinders St Station Underpass", "Melbourne Central", "Princes Bridge", "Sandridge Bridge", "State Library", "Town Hall (West)"),
                 locationMax = c(8592, 3213, 3127, 138, 4472, 3923, 4595, 1758, 4252, 2926))
df_list <- lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), function(x) mongo.bson.from.JSON(toJSON(x)))

mongo <- mongo.create()                                # connect to Mongo on localhost
if (mongo.is.connected(mongo) == TRUE) {
    icoll <- paste(db, "test", sep=".")
    mongo.insert.batch(mongo, icoll, df_list)          # insert into the MongoDB
    dbs <- mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, db)
    print(dbs)
    mongo.find.all(mongo, icoll)
}
```

Comment: When I run your code I get following error 
"Expected list of mongo.bson class objects"
So i converted it to BSON using "b = mongo.bson.from.JSON(df_list)"
then i get "Error: is.character(txt) is not TRUE". Any idea of fixing it?

Comment: @Ezio123 Sorry I forgot to use the `mongo.bson.from.JSON` function to parse each JSON object.  Try again...it should work now ^ ^

Comment: Im still getting "Error: is.character(txt) is not TRUE"

Comment: Follow this demo and see how far you can get: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/vignettes/rmongodb_introduction.html

Comment: The error you are getting is probably Mongo complaining that the JSON is not in the right format.  The code I gave for converting your data frame into JSON is basically correct.